# How does overriding equals and hashCode impacts storing data in a Map in Java with a bad hashing function?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashcode, equality

I have a class, `Employee`, let's say, and my `hashCode` function for this class is really bad (let's say it always return a constant). My code looks like the following.

```
public class Employee {
 private String name;

 public Employee(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 @Override
 public int hashCode() { return 1; }

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object object) {
  if(null == object || !(object instanceof Employee)) {
   return false;
  }
  Employee other = (Employee)object;
  return this.name.equals(other.name);
 }
}
```

Let's say I want to use `Employee` as the key in a `Map`, and so I can do something like the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Map<Employee, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
 for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
  map.put(new Employee("john"+i, 1L));
 }
 System.out.println(map.size());
}
```

How come when I run this code, I always get 1,000 as the size?

Using `Employee` as a key seems to be "good" in the following sense.

- It is immutable
- Two employees that are `equals` always generate the same hash code

What I expected was that since the output of `hashCode` is always 1, then `map.size()` should always be 1. But it is not. Why? If I have a `Map<Integer,Integer>`, and I do `map.put(1, 1)` followed by `map.put(1, 2)`, I would only expect the size to be 1.

The `equals` method must somehow be coming into play here, but I'm not sure how.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop

```
for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
    map.put(new Employee("john"+System.currentTimeMillis(), 1L));
}
```

executes within a couple of milliseconds, so `System.currentTimeMillis()` will be returning the same value for the vast majority of the iterations of your loop.  So, several hundred of your johns will have the exact same name + number.

Then, we have java's retarded `Map` which does not have an `add()` method, (which one would reasonably expect to throw an exception if the item already exists,) but instead it only has a `put()` method which will either add or replace items, without failing.  So, most of your johns get overwritten by subsequent johns, without any increase in the map size, and without any exception being thrown to give you a hint about what you are doing wrong.

Furthermore, you seem to be a bit confused as to exactly what the effect of a bad `hashCode()` function is on a map.  A bad `hashCode()` simply results in collisions.  Collisions in a hashmap do not cause items to be lost; they only cause the internal structure of the map to not be very efficient.  Essentially, a constant `hashCode()` will result in a degenerate map which internally looks like a linked list.  It will be inefficient both for insertions and for deletions, but no items will be lost due to that.

Items will be lost due to a bad `equals()` method, or due to overwriting them with newer items.  (Which is the case in your code.)

Comment: @ByeBye It IS taken in the equals method

Comment: @ByeBye Read the question.

Comment: Yes you are right. I'm going to modify my question a bit to avoid that problem.

Comment: You lost me on that middle paragraph. There's nothing retarded about the implementation. It is behaving exactly as documented. There is a `containsKey` method for determining if something will be overwritten.

Comment: I've modified the code slightly to avoid that problem. But now I get 1,000 as the size of the map. Shouldn't the hash code keep mapping the value to the same bucket?

Comment: @JaneWayne I added one more paragraph clearing up that bit.

Comment: @4castle compare java's `Map` with C#'s `IDictionary` and you will see what I mean by retarded and non-retarded.

Comment: @MikeNakis How is that retarded? They are separate implementations, which both work perfectly fine. I prefer to use `containsKey` instead of wait for an exception.

Comment: @4castle well, if that's what you prefer, then I can at the very least agree with you that it is a matter of preference.  I also "prefer" to call it retarded.  Let me point you to E.W. Dijkstra's quote lamenting many people's "preference" to "[...] equate "the ease of programming" with the ease of making undetected mistakes".

Answer (score 2):

Mike's answer is right about what is causing this. But the real reason that it's happening is this:

In the put method of HashMap it first checks the hashcode for each entry. If the hash code is equal to the hashcode of your new key then it checks for .equals(). If equals() returns true it just replaces the existing object with the new one otherwise adds a new key value pair. That's where it gets busted. Because somethings your equals() function will return true because of the currentMilliSeconds and sometimes it won't hence different sizes every time.

Just pay attention to the equals in the code below (java HashMap).

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your hashcode is the same for every entry then your time complexity will be O(n) because the hashcode creates buckets to store your elements.  If you only create a single bucket then you have to traverse the entire bucket to get your element.

If however, your hashcode is unique for every element then you will have a unique bucket and will only have to traverse a single element.

Bucket lookups (Hash) are O(1) so the better the hashcode the better the time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misconecption what `HashBuckets` in a `HashMap` are for.
When you put two `Objects`which are not equal but have the same `hashCode` in a  `HashMap`, both elements will be present in the `Hashmap` in the same `HashBucket`. An element is only overwritten when an element exists in the `HashMap`which has the same `hashCode` and is `equals` to an existing element.

The `HashBuckets` make the `HashMap` fast at lookup, because when searching for an element, only elements in the `HahsBucket` corresponding to the `hashCode` need to be considered. This is why it is generally a bad idea to wirte a `HashFunction` which is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Your `hashcode` has to comply with certain requirements e.g equal objects should return equal `hashcode`. 
But your implementation is not solid then it will give performance problem, if many of your objects have the same `hashcode` your look up some simply become O(N) instead of O(1). In your case it simply putting all items in a `List`. So the size is `1000`.